# Javascript, CSS: change JSON content display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I get JSON response in the following format:

```
{
    "title": "Title1",
    "link": "url",
    "description": "<p><a href=\"authorUrl\">Author<\/a> posted a photo:<\/p> 
                    <p><a href=\"url\" title=\"Title1\">
                    <img src=\"image1.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"240\" alt=\"Title1\"/><\/a><\/p>
                    <p>Post1 description<\/p>",
    "published": "2016-05-14T13:35:31Z",
    "tags": "tag1 tag2"
   }
```

I need to parse description and change the way it's rendered. I want to put image,text and tags in 2 columns within one div with class "row". So that in page it will look like:

```
  Author  |   Published: 14th May 2016 13:35

 ------------   
 |          |     Post1 description
 |image.jpg |   
 | 300x300  |
 ------------     
                  Tags: tag1, tag2
```

What is the best way to parse JSON and manipulate its content.
English is not my first language. I hope I stated problem clearly

Comment: `So that in page it will look like:` You want to display in table. Explain Clearly your requirement.

Comment: Why you used `title` and `url` twice in json(In json key and json description)?